# Projections onto convex sets and Lipschitz condition

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty convex set. Let $\pi_K$ be the projection onto $K$, that is, $$\pi_K(x)=\mathrm{argmin}_{k\in\mathbb{R}^n}\{\|x-k\|_2:k\in K\}.$$ Let $\|\cdot\|_2$ denote the Euclidean $2$-norm. I want to show that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $$\|\pi_K(x)-\pi_K(y)\|_2\le \|x-y\|_2.$$

An article I am reading claims this is trivial, but I'm not sure how to proceed. It seems intuitively true if $K$ is a projection onto a subspace, say onto $K=\mathrm{span}(e_1,\dots,e_k)$ for some $k<n$ (since in the last few coordinates, nothing is contributing to the $2$-norm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that since $K$ is convex from definition of the projection you have for all $k \in K$ and $\lambda \in (0 ,1)$ that $$ \| x - \pi_{K} (x) \|^2 \leq \|x -(\lambda k  +(1- \lambda) \pi_{K} (x)) \|^2  = \| x - \pi_{K} (x) -  \lambda (k - \pi_{K} (x)) \|^2$$
By opening up the above norm-squared and letting $\lambda \to 0$,  you can conclude that 
$$                       \langle x - \pi_{K} (x) \; , \; k -  \pi_{K} (x) \rangle  \leq 0  \quad \quad \forall k\in K $$
similarly 
$$                       \langle y - \pi_{K} (y) \; , \; k -  \pi_{K} (y) \rangle  \leq 0  \quad \quad \forall k\in K $$

Now by settting $k = \pi_{K} (y)$ in first inequality and then $k = \pi_{K} (x)$ in the second inequality, afteradding later inequality we have 
$$  \langle x-y + (\pi_{K}(y) - \pi_{K} (x) ) \; , \; \pi_{K}(y) -  \pi_{K} (x) \rangle  \leq 0    $$
Thus 
$$      \| \pi_{K}(y) - \pi_{K} (x)\|^2 \leq  \langle x-y  \; , \; \pi_{K}(y) -  \pi_{K} (x) \rangle  \leq \; \|  y -x \|  \; \| \pi_{K}(y) - \pi_{K} (x)\| $$
This gives you the desired inequality.

Comment: I'm actually not able to see the first inequality: how does one easily show this?

Comment: Just wrote one more line . Is it clear now? @FakeAnalyst56

Comment: Your most recent comment clarified the issue (the one using convexity and $\lambda$) and I managed to work out the details. Thank you very much for the additional help. @Red

Comment: The sad part is that I have answered this before and should know better :-( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1074244/27978.

Answer (score 4):

(This is a rewrite of an egregiously incorrect previous answer.)

I have always found the usual proof of this fact a little unsatisfactory and lacking in geometric intuition. Here is a more intuitive proof.

$K$ needs to be closed to ensure that a $\min$ exists.

We can assume that $\pi_K(x) \neq \pi_X(y)$ otherwise the result is trivial.

Let $L$ be the line $p(t) = \pi_K(x)+t (\pi_K(y)-\pi_K(y))$ and let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto this line. It is straightforward to show that $\|P\| = 1$, and hence $\|Px-Py\| \le \|x-y\|$. This is the essential fact here.

Let $t_x,t_y$ be such that $p(t_x) = Px, p(t_y) = Py$. Note that we
must have $t_x \le 0$ and $t_y \ge 1$, as otherwise the definition of $\pi_K(x)$
or $\pi_K(y)$ would be contradicted.
Then $\|Px-Py\| = \|p(t_x)-p(t_y)\| = (t_y-t_x) \| \pi_K(x)-\pi_K(y)\| \ge \| \pi_K(x)-\pi_K(y)\|$.

**Addendum**:

To see why $t_x \le 0$, let $\phi(t)=\|x-p(t)\|^2 = \|x-Px\|^2+(t-t_x)^2\|\pi(x)-\pi(y)\|^2$.

Note that $\phi$ is convex, strictly decreasing for $t \le t_x$ and strictly increasing for $t \ge t_x$.
Also note that $p(t) \in K$ for $t \in [0,1]$ so $\phi(t) \ge \phi(0)$ on $t \in [0,1]$.

In particular, we must have $t_x \le 0$ otherwise $\phi$ would be strictly decreasing on $[0,t_x]$ which would be a contradiction.

Comment: Well, any norm and projection $\pi_K$ that satisfies the above will give the above result, but it does not hold for an arbitrary norm. At a minimum, the minimiser must be unique.

Comment: You can't take $c =x$ !

Comment: @Redshoes: Silly me. Will fix.

Comment: Hmm. I can't delete my answer.

Comment: I dont care :)  The thing is that My intuition tells me that this claim is not true for any arbitrary   norm ! At least not true with lipschitz constant 1. 
So any proof using only the norm of the space might be incorrect. that's made me go through your proof and find the draw back.

Comment: Thanks for catching the issue @Red shoes. I was too suspicious about the 'any norm' part since the paper I'm reading is trying to prove it holds for general norms! This makes more sense

Comment: It is not true for an arbitrary norm, it is easy to create a counterexample with the 1 or $\infty$ norm.

Comment: I have added a completely different proof.