# Gradient of $\mbox{dist}\left(x, D \right)^2:= \left\| x - P_{D}(x)\right\|_2^2$, where $P_{D}(x)$ is a projection operator

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a non empty convex closed set and:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}, f(x)=(\operatorname{dist}(x,D))^{2}$$

Prove that f is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and

$$f'(x)=2(x-P_{D}(x)), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n},$$ where $\mbox{dist}(x,D)$ is the distance between a point $x$ and the set $D$ and $P_{D}(x)$ is the projection of $x$ in $D$, i.e.,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{dist}\left(x, D \right) := \left\| x -  P_{D}(x)\right\|_2.
\end{align}

Comment: What techniques have you tried so far?

Comment: @TSF $P_D$ is not differentiable at the boundary of $D$

Comment: @LinAlg is the expression given for gradient true? Suppose, if we prove $f$ is differentiable. Can you give a hint how to find gradient of $P_D(x)$?

Comment: @ShivTavker yes, this formula is correct (and the generalization in (*) below is also true). Hint: If $f$ has a gradient, then the directional derivative of $f$ at $x_0$, denoted $f(x,x_0)$, is linear as a function of the direction. The gradient is the slope of this linear functional and is represented (a la Hahn Banach Theorem) via $f(x,x_0)=\langle x \, | \nabla f(x_0)\rangle$

Comment: The project is not differentiable. Take $D$ to be the closed unit square in the plane and note that  $P_D((x,2) = (\max(1,|x|),1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tedious but elementary proof.

Note that the projection is Lipschitz with rank one, that is $\|P_D(x)-P_D(y)\| \le \|x-y\|$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3272169/27978) for example).

Note that $f(y) \le \|y-P_D(x)\|^2 = \|x-P_D(x)+y-x\|^2 = f(x) + 2(x-P_D(x))^T(y-x) +\|y-x\|^2$ so we have
$f(y)-f(x) - 2(x-P_D(x))^T(y-x) \le \|y-x\|^2$.

Swapping $x,y$ we get
$-(f(y)-f(x) - 2(y-P_D(y))^T(y-x))  \le \|y-x\|^2$.

Note that $y-P_D(y) = x-P_D(x) + y-x+P_D(x)-P_D(y)$, so the above becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
-(f(y)-f(x) - 2(x-P_D(x))^T(y-x)) &\le & \|y-x\|^2-2(y-x+P_D(x)-P_D(y))(y-x) \\
&\le& 4 \|y-x\|^2
\end{eqnarray}
In particular, $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and
$D f(x)h = 2(x-P_D(x))^T h$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fast way of proving this as a corollary of the result
$$\nabla(M_{\gamma f})=\gamma^{-1}(\textrm{Id}-\textrm{prox}_{\gamma f}),\tag{*}$$
where $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$ and $M_{\gamma f}$ is the [Moreau Envelope](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Moreau_envelope_function) of a proper, lower-semicontinuous, convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to]-\infty,+\infty]$. This result appears in Corollary 12.31 of Bauschke & Combettes' book, vol. 2. The argument essentially states that if you let $\gamma=1/2$ and let $f$ be the [$0$-$\infty$ indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)) of the set $D$, then $M_{\gamma f}=\textrm{dist}^2_D/2$ and $\textrm{prox}_{\gamma f}=P_D$. Then you just multiply (*) to get the factor of $2$.

I'd be interested to see a more direct proof using less "heavy-duty" machinery.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using non differentiable calculus.

Let $d_D(x) = \min_{d \in D} \|x-d\|^2$. The $\min$ is attained at a unique point $P_D(x)$ because $D$ is closed & convex.

If we pick some $x^*$ and restrict $x$ to the closed ball $\overline{B}(x^*,1)$, we can assume that $D$ is compact. To see this, pick $R=\sqrt{d_D(x^*)}+1$ and let $D' = D \cap \overline{B}(x^*,R)$. Then
$d_D(x) \le \|x-P_D(x^*)\|^2 \le (\|x-x^*\| + \sqrt{d_D(x^*)})^2 \le R^2$.
In particular, $P_D(x) \in D'$ and so, locally, $d_D(x) = d_{D'}(x)$, so we may assume that $D$ is bounded and hence compact.

We can write $d_D(x) = - g(x)$, where $g(x)=\max_{d \in D} \phi(x,d)$ and $\phi(x,d) = - \|x-d\|^2 $. Since $g$ is locally Lipschitz it has a (Clarke) generalised gradient and
we can compute it by $\partial g(x) = \operatorname{co} \{ { \partial \phi(x,d) \over \partial x} \}_{d \in I(x)}$ with $I(x) = \{ d \in D | \phi(d,x) = g(x) \}$. Since the maximiser is unique, it turns out that $g$ is differentiable and ${\partial g(x) \over \partial x} = { \partial \phi(x,P_D(x)) \over \partial x} = - 2(x-P_D(x))^T$. Hence
$d_D$ is differentiable and
${\partial d_D(x) \over \partial x} = 2(x-P_D(x))^T$.